# Log in required when moving to SuperUser on iPad?

Tags: support, bug

When moving around the sites on StackExchange using Safari on my iPad (not the StackExchange App), I am fine when moving to any site other than SuperUser.  When logged in I can switch sites and stay logged in, but when I switch to SuperUser I need to log in again.

If I choose not to log in and switch to another site I am logged in there.

Is there a problem with the log in handling for SuperUser?